# fill in a field with the concatenation of 2 other fields on load before add

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, concatenation, onload-event

I have a PHP page to add data to  database the form has the fields:

`BalanceNo`,  `Customer`, `InvoiceNo`,  I am using javascript to  fill on the fly  ; on load  in the field  `BalanceNo` with the value of `Customer` and  `InvoiceNo` which would look like `Nicolas-009`or somthing like that
I wrote this code but it fills `BalanceNo` only with  the value of `customerNo`

```
 var ctrl11 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'InvoiceNo');
 var ctrl1 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Customer');
 var ctrl2 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'BalanceNo');

function CalNo()
 { 

var value2=ctrl1.getValue();
var value1=ctrl11.getValue();
ctrl2.setValue(value2,value1);
 };

ctrl11.on('change',function(e){ CalNo(); } );
ctrl1.on('change',function(e){ CalNo(); } );
```

Please Help

Comment: It looks like you are filling in the balanceNo with customer+invoice. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes Exactly  , but i want it to be done while  entering data, before i click on Save

Comment: You probably need to assign the onchage events to the elements themselves and not a `Runner.getControl` object.

Comment: It is  working not but the problem still the concatenation :ctrl2.setValue(value2,value1);  i think  there should be mistake  in this part of the code

Comment: try `ctrl2.setValue(value2+value1);`

Comment: @tristansokol   It worked  Yes , Thank you very much